# amp pages stopped working. cdn.ampproject.org resources cannot be loaded

Tags: javascript, html, https, amp-html

Today we observed the first time a problem on our amp version of [parkscanner.de](https://www.parkscanner.de)

On the desktop-browser the [amp version](https://www.parkscanner.de/amp/) runs fine.

But on some mobile devices e.g. Android with Chrome, or Firefox or Firefox Beta, it leads to errors. But on IPhones it works.

We connected the Android Device with the Firefox Developer edition and the [remote debugging freatures](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging) to the computer.

There I get the strange error, that

> the resources from cdn.ampproject.org could not be loaded.

What looks suspicious is that the Referrer Policy on the amp servers is set to "same-origin".

How can we solve this issue? It would be great if all the amp resources could be loaded on all devices.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I do not understand about this new tag. amp-project.Can you eloborate ?

Comment: Worked for me on Android/Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Check is the AMP project is not blocked in your country, As it's blocked in Egypt Also.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/10409474?hl=en